# how do I get my password prompt back?

Tags: safari, password

I recently installed a password manager and since then, Safari no longer prompts me to use saved passwords when signing in to websites etc. I have turned the password manager extension off but Safari still doesn't give me any prompts. How do I turn this back on?

I'm using Big Sur 11.6.2

Comment: Which password manager?

Comment: keeper password manager